# CORS Policy Error when Sending POST Request to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, cors

I am trying to make a POST request to a Google Apps Script web app, but I'm encountering a CORS policy error. I've provided the code for both the client-side JavaScript and the Google Apps Script server-side code below. Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can resolve it? I have tried many similar solution but none work for me
this is my errror

```
Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/{redacted}' from origin 'https://docs.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
```

Client-Side JavaScript Chrome Extension:

```
 
function sendRequestToAppsScript(action) {
    console.log('heard');
    fetch(webAppUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ action: action }),
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  
    })
    .then(response => response )
    .then(data => {
        // Log the response from Google Apps Script
        console.log('Response from Google Apps Script:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

Google Apps Script (Server-Side):

javascript

```
function doPost(e) {
    var result;
    dosomething();
    Logger.log("doPost called");

    // Set up the CORS headers
    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    };

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ result: result }))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
        .setHeaders(headers);
}
```

I've  tried  to set the mode to 'no-cors' in the fetch request, and I've added CORS headers on the server-side, but I'm still encountering a CORS policy error . What am I missing here, and how can I successfully make this POST request to my Google Apps Script web app?

Comment: An opaque response doesn’t serve your needs since you need data back, so no-cors is not suitable.

Comment: I know I removed it but I still have a cors issue

Comment: Can I ask you about the setting of your Web Apps? What are the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, in your situation, the account of your Web Apps is in Google workspace? First, I would like to correctly understand your situation.